# Symmetrical Difference (Understanding the scope of this function)

Tags: javascript, arrays, scope, closures, reduce

I was completing a task of FCC which was to get the symmetrical difference of a varied number of arrays. Part of the reason I got stuck was because of my placement of the results array where I would push the unique elements to.I had it outside the function makeSym and I needed to have it inside which i discovered when checking out the hints page. But I dont know why.

```
function sym() {

    var results = []; // I had the results array here rather than inside function makeSym


    var allArrays = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        allArrays.push(arguments[i]);
    }

    function makeSym(arrOne, arrTwo) {

        // when the results array was placed here, it worked

        arrOne.forEach(function (a) {
            if (arrTwo.indexOf(a) === -1 && results.indexOf(a) === -1) {
                results.push(a);
            }
        });

        arrTwo.forEach(function (a) {
            if (arrOne.indexOf(a) === -1 && results.indexOf(a) === -1) {
                results.push(a);
            }
        });

        return results;
    }

    return allArrays.reduce(makeSym);

}

sym([1, 1, 2, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5], [3, 4, 5, 5]);
```

My question is why does this change my result, why don't I get the correct symmetrical difference. What is happening in the mechanics that I was missing.
the difference between these two placements was a return of 1,4,5 and a result of 1,3,4,5 (the correct answer should be 1,4,5)

I am assuming this has something to do with scope and closure and this is something I really want to understand more, any information would be helpful.

The second part of my question for anyone still with me, is why does the reduce work in this, what is the reduce doing. I understand its reducing to a single array my multiple arrays but how come the function makeSym doesnt do this alone, in my mind I should be able to execute the function with allArrays as a parameter then return results and complete the challenge this way, but this doesnt work and the reason why it doesnt work isnt obvious to me at all. Again any elucidation would help me understand this more and move forward. Cheers

Comment: Why `1, 4, 5` not `1, 4`?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko: "1,4,5" is the correct answer, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#n-ary_symmetric_difference